# The quartic electronic state of octahedral Fe(III): How make crystal field splitting diagram?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, transition-metals, crystal-field-theory

Using simple arguments from crystal field theory, how do I rationalize the quartic state of octahedral Fe(III)? I am not able to in a logical way distribute the 5 d electrons in such a a way as to end up with three unpaired electrons in the normal splitting diagram for octahedral complexes.

Comment: Fe(III) has $5 d$ electrons. If the $\Delta_O$ value is small, the five $d$ levels are all occupied by $1$ electron. This is a stable situation.

Comment: Do you mean the quartic excited state? start with low spin $t_{2g}^5$ and excite one of the paired $t_{2g}$ electrons to $e_g$.